# Rstudio running local job produce a different effect from interactive mode when sourcing function

Tags: r, rstudio

to reproduce this effect, we need two files,both stored in your working directory:

file1: f.R  just one line:

```
f = function(){print('whatever you like')}
```

file2: execute_in_jobs.R

```
source('f.R')
print(environment(f)) #get the closure name of f

f = function(){print('whatever you like')}
print(environment(f)) #get the closure name of f
```

if you run execute_in_jobs.R in interactive, both print result is global env.

if you run execute as local job in Rstudio, the sourced f will print result global env while the f defined in current R file will show different result (another enclousure environment name)

My guess is the source command is running in global env while the function defined in job file is running in some local env, but I was wondering why.

This will sometimes produce unexpected result.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Windows?! Already tried `setwd()` on top of each script?

Comment: @jay.sf you mean you can't run the code or you can run but the result is not as decribed,  I can reproduce this in linux and just tried in windows and it can be reproduced in windows, the output is <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: 0x00000280e7dd27e8>.

Comment: Getting always global env. Tried explicit `setwd`? What do you mean exactly by "run execute as local job"? Versions R, RStudio?

Comment: @jay.sf in Rstudio, you have "background jobs" close to console, or you can click the some arrow next to source and choose "source as background job" to do this.